# How to transform a list of strings into a hierarchical DataFrame where the strings of each column is contained in the strings of the next column?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, text-classification, hierarchical-clustering

I have a list of thousands strings and I would like to organize them into a DataFrame where each row are the "path" of each term and each column are like levels, that can be variable. Thus, in all rows, the string contained in a column x is contained in the string in x + 1 column, which in turn is contained in x + 2 and so on. Another requisite is that the match is for entire word, returning false if a string is only a substring inside another word. In summary:

```
terms = ["term a",
         "term a term b",
         "word",
         "word a term b",
         "words",
         "contains words",
         "term a contains",
         "term b contains words",
         "term a term b contains words"]
```

I would like a function that returns:

|  | level_0 | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | term a |  |  |  |
| 1 | term a | term a term b |  |  |
| 2 | word |  |  |  |
| 3 | word | word a term b |  |  |
| 4 | words |  |  |  |
| 5 | words | contains words |  |  |
| 6 | term a | term a contains |  |  |
| 7 | words | contains words | term b contains words |  |
| 8 | words | contains words | term b contains words | term a term b contains words |

I managed to build a function that makes what I needed, but for thousands terms, it is very slow, mainly by `re.search` with boundaries, where I noticed a great time increment after the implementation, but anyway, I think that function could be optimized and less code could be written.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import itertools

def organize_terms(terms):

    levels = {}
    path = {}
    terms_copy = terms.copy()

    # Defines which level each term belongs to

    count = 0

    while len(terms) > 0:

        levels[f"level_{count}"] = []

        for term in terms:
            temp = [term_2 for term_2 in terms if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(term_2), term) != None and len(term_2.split()) < len(term.split())]
            if temp == []:
                levels[f"level_{count}"].append(term)
        
        terms = [x for x in terms if x not in levels[f"level_{count}"]]
        
        count += 1

    """
    levels = {'level_0': ['term a', 'word', 'words'],
              'level_1': ['term a term b', 'word a term b', 'contains words', 'term a contains'],
              'level_2': ['term b contains words'],
              'level_3': ['term a term b contains words']}
    """

    for key in levels.keys():
        path[key] = []

    for term in terms_copy:

        # Maps all compatible combinations for each term

        matches = []
        for level in levels.keys():
            level_match = [term_2 for term_2 in levels[level] if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(term_2), term) != None]
            if level_match != []:
                matches.append(level_match)

        combinations = list(itertools.product(*matches))

        """
        combinations = [('term a',)]
        combinations = [('term a', 'term a term b')]
        combinations = [('word',)]
        combinations = [('word', 'word a term b')]
        combinations = [('words',)]
        combinations = [('words', 'contains words')]
        combinations = [('term a', 'term a contains')]
        combinations = [('words', 'contains words', 'term b contains words')]
        combinations = [('term a', 'term a term b', 'term b contains words', 'term a term b contains words'),
                        ('term a', 'contains words', 'term b contains words', 'term a term b contains words'),
                        ('words', 'term a term b', 'term b contains words', 'term a term b contains words'),
                        ('words', 'contains words', 'term b contains words', 'term a term b contains words')]
        """

        # Checks if each term is contained in the next and, if so, adds to the path variable

        for combination in combinations:
            confirmation = all([re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(combination[i-1]), combination[i]) != None for i in range(1, len(combination))])
            if confirmation:
                list_combination = list(combination)
                while len(list_combination) < len(levels.keys()):
                    list_combination.append(None)
                for idx, combination_term in enumerate(list_combination):
                    path[f"level_{idx}"].append(combination_term)
         
    """
    path = {'level_0': ['term a', 'term a', 'word', 'word', 'words', 'words', 'term a', 'words', 'words'],
            'level_1': [None, 'term a term b', None, 'word a term b', None, 'contains words', 'term a contains', 'contains words', 'contains words'],
            'level_2': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'term b contains words', 'term b contains words'],
            'level_3': [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'term a term b contains words']}
    """

    # Returns the DataFrame

    return pd.DataFrame(path)
```

Furthermore, for testing purposes, I made this little function to substitute `re.search` with boundaries which proved to be faster for thousands of terms.

```
from nltk import ngrams

def search(term1, term2):
    ngram_list = [' '.join(tuples) for tuples in list(ngrams(term2.split(), len(term1.split())))]
    return term1 in ngram_list
```

Even though, I think that functions could be faster. You would have a suggestion to optimize (or redo) these functions?

Comment: Why don't you just use string function instead of regex. For eg: "find" in string.split()

Comment: Because the substring may be a term and I need to find the substring in a string *as a complete word or term*. I tried to use an approach that checks if each word of *substring.split()* is in *string.split()*, returning *True* if all of these checks are *True*, but these approach ignores the substring word order.

Comment: What is the difference between term and word ?